# GSM extended character encoding issues when submitting data to api

Tags: java, character-encoding, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

Im having some issues when submitting a url through curl to my api.
The url parameter im using to test is &body=+%bb%3d+ that is in the special character set for gms and id suppose to be a '~'.

When i print out the value I get  '�='

Now I know that its not in the utf-8 character set and thats the reason that the unicode replacement character is getting substituted.

There has to be a way of getting the data to my server with out the substitution.
Im running a java project using jetty and jersey.

---EDIT---

Ok I have tried the

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String submit(@QueryParam("from") String from, @QueryParam("to") String to, @QueryParam("body") String body) {
        byte[] raw = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        body = new String(raw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("data - " + body);
```

Which prints out data -  ?= 
Changing the charset from US_ASCII to ISO_8859_1 prints out data -  ?=

Comment: What character encoding are you using on the request?  and what character encoding are you expecting to use?

Comment: The characters that im expecting is ASCII characters, Im adding the following header to curl Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=US-ASCII.

Comment: Let me be alittle clearer, Im expecting a extendend gsm character or a greek character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended character encoding per the HTTP spec is`UTF-8`, hence why you are getting that result.  Your code might be relying on a little known behavior of RFC2616 that said in the absence of an encoding assume `ISO-8859-1`, which as a practice was later dropped in RFC7231 in favor of `UTF-8` everywhere unless declared to be otherwise.

If you want a different encoding when parsing parameters, set it at the time you pull it out of the request object, or use the UTF8 equivalent.

Eg:

```java
/* will decode all parameters, header values, and content as ISO-8859-1 */
request.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
String actual = request.getParameter("body");
System.out.println("\"" + actual + "\"");

/* output on console of : " »= " */
/* that's a RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK followed by an EQUALS */
```

If you want to use the `UTF8` equivalent of that, then [use `%C2%BB%3D`](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=00BB&mode=hex)

Option #2, decode raw parameter after the fact.

```java
String raw = request.getParameter("body");
byte[] bytes = raw.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);  // decode
String actual = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**Update #1: 2013-Oct-03**

The outcome you are seeing when you set `US-ASCII` is correct.

The value `%bb` is above the 7-bit limit of US-ASCII, so its being shown in the substitution character.

Example Java:

```
    // as us-ascii
    String decoded = URLDecoder.decode("+%bb%3d+",StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.name());
    System.out.printf("Decoded: '%s'%n",decoded);
```

**Update #1: 2013-Oct-03**

As for the GSM character set, I can find no built-into Java support for any of the GSM character sets, you'll want to bone up on Charsets, Encoding, etc, and then, when you are very comfortable with it, you can look into 3rd party libraries for java that will take either UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 and translate them to one of the 50 published GSM Charsets.

Example (of just 1 GSM Charset designation):

http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/java-gsm-0338-sms-character-set-translator/

Or you can find the UTF-8 character you want, pop it into an [online UTF-8 Tool](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi) (as a character), and backtrack it to the Hex Code Point that you then use.

Comment: You see the body get passed as a query parameter. But when I get it on the server the %bb has been replace with a replacement character

Comment: It needs to be utf-8 that is I get the raw and replace "\u00bb\u003d" with ~

Comment: %c2%bb%3d also outputs  �=

Comment: I got it working thanks for that, the next problem i am facing is with the greek characters. When sending it as a url parameter I get the following error org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Dc in state 2